# Physical dimension of a complex wave function.

Tags: physics, quantum-mechanics, dimensional-analysis

If the probability density function $\rho$ is:

$$\rho=\psi^{*}\psi=|\psi|^2$$

where $\psi$ is a complex wave function that is a solution to the Schrodinger equation, what are the physical dimensions of $\psi$?

surly:

$$\dim(\rho)=\dim(\psi^2)$$

$$\dim(\rho)^{1/2}=\dim(\psi)$$

But what are the dimensions of a pdf?

Comment: You'd probably be better off asking this at physics.stackexchange.com

Comment: Actually, probability has no dimensions. So a pdf has dimensions of  $[L]^{-3}$, where $[L]$ denotes the dimensions of length. For a more quantity of answers you should ask this question in the Physics page, as @Neal said.